# range extender throttling whole home network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking, throttling, cellular-internet

So, I live in the boonies. No hard line high speed internet. Closest thing I have is a wifi puck (VZW RC400L). Verizon's home cellular is not offered in my area (has physical ehternet port).This "puck" has no hard connection. It provides wireless ONLY via 2.4ghz and 5ghz broadcasts. On my home network, I have a netgear 10 port hub, my desktop pc, nintendo switch, PS4, yamaha home amplifier, and synology ds920+. In order to provide connectivity to these devices, I have a wifi range extender connected to my puck's wifi, and providing ethernet signal to my 10 port switch. Warning, this scenario happens on BOTH 5ghz, and 2.4ghz connections as well as various range extenders. After a couple of hours of connectivity, my range extender THROTTLES my whole network down from 110mbps to <7mbps. When I try to connect to plex on my synology, I can surf my listings, but streaming gets scaled back due to throttling. If I disconnect the range extender, suddenly my transfer ratesspike to zero, but go back up to 110+mbps after the lag. However, then my computer also has to "rediscover" my network places. When I plug my range extender back in, I still have fast transfers, and get my internet back, but ... in an hour or three (randomly), it gets throttled again. This happens with two different Netgear ex7300's and with a TP-link AC750. It happened with my old windows 7 pro machine, and my new 11 pro machine. I dont think it has anything to do with windows. I'm very convinced it has everything to do with my range extender since it goes away when I power fail that device particularly, however I'm open to possibilities it may be a networking issue between various components. Has anyone else experienced this? I know my situation is somewhat uncommon, so many may not have experienced this or attempted troubleshooting. I'm just looking for some help to make my home network more stable, and not have to get up regularly to rip the range extender out of the wall, and plug it back in... Thank you to whomever responds!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please give your post some shape. It's hard to understand a wall of text.

Comment: Also, a better description of your network would be helpful - why are you using a ranfe extender rather then an AP client, and how is it that this "puck" works but other verizon connectivity doesnt?  Range extenders are horrible devices with no placr in a properly designed network

Answer (score 0):

1. You need a router on your network
2. Setup a sepparate PC that has a wireless and wired NIC as a proxy server
3. Use the router to manage DHCP for your LAN.
4. Use the proxy server to provide internet access to your LAN

Item 2 can be handled a few ways different ways but but that's the basics.  If (when)  Internet blips and/or goes down, network doesn't go bananas.